# Почему популярность Си увеличивается?

Tags: c

[TIOBE Programming Community Index for August 2012](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html)

Может мне кто-нибудь пояснить, почему популярность Си увеличивается!? Что на нём вообще пишут, кроме прог для микроконтроллеров, низкоуровневых системных утилит и драйверов?

[image]

Comment: Кстати, индекс TIOBE опирается и на такие метрики как, например, частота поисковых запросов. Есть индекс от BlackDuck Software, который тоже конечно многокритериальный, но преимущественно опирается на анализ кода в открытых репозиториях - там популярность Си еще выше.

Comment: Black Duck Software [open source project releases](http://osrc.blackducksoftware.com/data/projects/)

46% C и 12% С++ впечатляет.

Comment: Что на нём вообще пишут, кроме прог для микроконтроллеров, низкоуровневых системных утилит, драйверов, операционных систем и софта для них? // fixed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Откровенно порадовался.

Более того, уверен, что больше половины программ на С++ на самом деле являются программами на C, использующими `cin`,`cout`, `string`, ну может быть еще `vector` и какие-то библиотеки, написанные на С++. Но по стилю (духу) они все равно остаются С программами.

Основная причина в том, что C - **это простой язык**.

[@barmaley](/users/5648/barmaley), хорошо намекнул на его роль. По моему опыту на нем много пишут разных серверных конверторов, врапперов, прокси и т.п. Часто именно на C проще всего эффективно закодировать какую-нибудь нетривиальную обработку данных (в файле, потоке) и вызывать ее, скажем, из ПХП.

Comment: > Более того, уверен, что больше половины программ на С++ на самом деле являются программами на C, использующими cin,cout, string, ну может быть еще vector и какие-то библиотеки

Постоянно анализируя университетские курсы и учебники, убеждаюсь, что и они, как правило, представляют собой курсы по Си с классами потокового ввода-вывода, перегрузкой, шаблонами и парой примеров контейнеров. Всё-таки, C++ - это философия и явно не для вводных курсов. Сам читаю Си в пределах C99 (в этом году, может, включу обзор C11) в рамках одного семестра, а уже затем коллеги навешивают C++, Java, C# и т.п.

Comment: @northerner, очень правильный подход. Сначала С, потом С++ и прочие прелести жизни. Плюсую обеими руками.

Comment: Как ни крути, а С++ все-таки остается С с классами. До более высоких материй - обобщенное программирование, метапрограммирование - из-за сложности предмета способны дойти очень немногие программисты.

Comment: вспоминается картинка "С++ за 21 день"

Comment: @mikillskegg, для 99% задач такие высокие материи просто не нужны. 

Более того, кому нужна программа, код которой понятен 10% программистов?

Comment: @avp, тоже правильно. Но все-таки классы очень часто являются весьма приятной добавкой к Си, поэтому я в последнее время переехал на плюсы. С++11 сделал программирование в нем еще более приятным. Кроме того, периодически пишу низкоуровневые модули для питона, а на Boost.Python они делаются как семечки.

Comment: @mikillskegg, согласен.

Comment: @Spectre Это-то тут причём? http://www.williamspublishing.com/21-days.html

@avp *Более того, кому нужна программа, код которой понятен 10% программистов?* 10% -- это мало или много? (Мне лично кажется, что это очень много)

Comment: @alexlz [может быть это?][1]

 [1]:http://www.calmworks.com/ImagesForSites/C++21day.jpg

Comment: @rasmisha Я не помню, видел ли эту картинку раньше. А вот книг, подобных описанным Норвигом, на полках видел и не раз.

Comment: @avp: Неубедительно, на самом деле. Паскаль, скажем, такой же простой язык, различия в семантике не сколько либо значительны. В ML'ях тоже можно найти очень простое императивное подмножество. Основная причина того, что на них не пишут, все же, в том, что *нет традиции* на них писать. Им не учат в школе, их мало трогают в ВУЗах, на них меньше написано существующего софта и т.д.. Это же, перевернуто, и основная причина популярности C. А «простой» язык или «сложный» тут уже дело второе.

Comment: По поводу Паскаля, согласен. Просто его (скорее Дельфи) вообще нет на графике (это меня, вообще-то, удивило). 

А ведь на Паскале было написано немало софта. В том числе, если не ошибаюсь, Apollo Domain OS и куча программ для авионики в Honeywell.

Comment: Паскаль ИМХО губит отсуствие четкой привязки или кросплатформенности, посмотрите внимательно на график, все языки там либо жестко привязаны к платформе и являются на ней основными с поддержкой производителя платформы(obj-c для маков и айоси, с# для винды и прочих продуктов мс, даже vb для мс офиса),либо они кросплатформенные и им все равно в чем работать, а борланд такой явной привязки не имело и кросплатформенность не осилила, да и нынешний хозяин этим не блещет.

Comment: @aknew Паскаль изначально вообще не предназначался для работы. Чисто учебный язык. Попытки сделать его рабочим были более или менее успешными, но порождения Борланда -- ужасные мутанты, от которых лучше держаться подальше.

Comment: Но увы, только эти порождения и используются в основном, по крайней мере я с другими никогда не сталкивался (клоны типа лазарус не берем).
А как учебный он весьма неплох, у меня он и был в институте самым первым.

Comment: Как учебный он был весьма неплох в 70х-80х. Возможно в 90х. Сейчас -- "нафиг, нафиг".

И его предшественник, Basic, был тоже неплох. В 60х...

Comment: @aknew, по поводу кроссплатформенности (скорее распространенности на разных платформах) Паскаля, не могу согласится с Вами.

В 70-е и 80-е Паскаль был почти на всех машинах. 

Повспоминав немного, думаю, что погубили его C вместе с Unix, а точнее доступность исходников софта. Собственно почти все в unix написано на C и исходники как ядра, так и всех этих интересных программ были доступны. Да и хакерство на C проще.

Вот и потихоньку все кто полюбопытней и потолковей перекочевали туда. Следствием явилось забвение Паскаля активной частью программистов-хакеров, а потом и остальными.

Comment: Cи - это простой язык? Нет. Си - это хороший язык

Answer (score 13):

Си часто используется в качестве промежуточного языка при разработке новых языков более высокого уровня. В последнее время новых языков стало появляться столько, что не хватает людей, квалификация которых позволяла бы написать компилятор, транслирующий программу сразу в машинные коды. Поэтому для большинства вновь появляющихся языков делаются трансляторы, формирующие на выходе программу на Си, которая затем компилируется обычным образом под любую платформу.

Comment: Транслировать языки сразу с машкод -- немного мартышкин труд. Тем более, проблемы межязыковых связей растут. Правда C в этой области должен потихоньку уходить. См., например, C--

Comment: C-- - это почти ассемблер. Так что это скорее он должен уходить оттуда, куда приходит Си, который по отношению к нему является языком более высокого уровня.

Comment: Который C-- ?

Comment: Sphinx C--

Comment: @Shamov Увлекаетесь археологией?

Comment: Нет. Просто я застал ещё те времена, когда Sphinx C-- был актуальным инструментом. О том, что существуют какие-то другие языки с тем же названием, даже и не знал.

Comment: @Shamov Саксаул? Пардон, аксакал? (это же где-то первая половина 90х, кажется?)

Comment: Скорее вторая. Ближе к началу нулевых.

Comment: На сайте [SPHINX C--](http://c--sphinx.narod.ru/) написано

    Последняя авторская версия SPHINX C-- v0.203 от 28.Oct.96.

@alexlz, а что тогда скажете про [BLISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLISS)?

Comment: Для написания компиляторов удобнее использовать LLVM, чем трансляцию в C.

Answer (score 13):

Глядя на 10-летний тренд я бы усомнился в росте востребованности C - он остается примерно постоянным - что только свидетельствует о том, что язык уже состоялся без резких спадов и подъемов он имеет свою устойчивую долю.

Распространенное убеждение о том, что С язык для программирования драйверов/контроллеров в корне неверно.  Это системный язык *NIX подобных осей и как правильно отметил камрад [@Shamov](/users/8566/shamov), это язык языков. В последние годы в Java тоже началась такая же тенденция: Clojure, Groovy, Scala все базируются на Java.

Comment: Не смешивайте Java-the-language и Java-the-bytecode. Тот же Clojure к языку Java отношение имеет, в общем-то, не больше, чем язык Java к C.

Comment: @drdaeman Clojure конечно совсем не Java, особенно умиляет Hello World на нем: `(javax.swing.JOptionPane/showMessageDialog nil "Hello World" )` - невооруженным глазом видно совсем не Swing :)

Comment: @Barmaley: И где тут Java-как-язык?

Видно почти обычный лисп. Почти — потому что каноничнее было бы как в CLOS, `(showMessageDialog JOptionPane nil "Hello World")`, но как сделали так сделали, автор-барин. И еще видно куски JRE, которое языком не является, так же, как CLR не является C#'ом.

Или кто-то в пайтоновом коде `s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)` видит C?

Кроме всего этого, помимо реализации ClojureJVM есть ведь ClojureCLR и ClojureScript, которые вообще к экосистеме Java не имеют отношения.

Answer (score 10):

[GitHub](http://github.com/search?q=language%3Ac) как бы намекает что на си пишутся только проги для микроконтроллеров, низкоуровневые системные утилиты и драйверы ;-)

Answer (score 9):

Подобные рейтинги учитывают в первую очередь языки, на которых пишутся открытые проекты. А поскольку большинство таковых пишется в первую очередь с расчетом на Линукс, а  С до сих пор остается очень популярным для разработки в разных никсах, то С имеет очень высокий рейтинг среди опенсорсов.

Интереснее было определить рейтинг языков в разработке коммерческих продуктов. Но сделать это очень сложно, а может, и практически невозможно.

Comment: >рейтинг языков в разработке коммерческих продуктов

для такого рейтинга можно использовать кол-во вакансий на популярных и/или не очень ресурсах

Comment: Кстати, очень здравая идея. Мне она тоже в голову приходила. Здесь, безусловно, Си оказывается не очень востребованным.

Comment: По моему, оценка по количеству вакансий показывает уровень понимания существа дела не слишком успешными работодателями, ищущими не самых лучших работников.

Поясню. 

1. В хорошую (действительно стоящую) компанию с улицы не попадешь.

2. Хорошие программисты не рассылают резюме.

Comment: И тем не менее, мне кажется, пропорции использования языков в коммерческом секторе это очень неплохо отображает.

Comment: Или текучку кадров для сопровождения программ на этих языках.

Comment: @avp Комментарии к ответу @Shamov уже заполнены, поэтому напишу здесь. Про BLISS ничего не скажу (просто потому, что ничего не знаю). Если у BCPL я хотя бы когда-то читал описание, то про BLISS я и этого сказать не могу.

Comment: @alexlz, да то был комментарий не по поводу собственно BLISS (это старый язык), а шуточка насчет *аксакалов*.

Comment: Про BLISS я вообще не в курсе. Так что не такой уж я и аксакал. Рано меня со счетов списывать :)

Answer (score 7):

Что-то я по графику не вижу, чтобы она увеличивалась. Как была, так примерно и осталась.

Я считаю, что одним из основных преимуществ C является то, что библиотеки, написанные на нём, можно использовать в любом языке, а для библиотек на других языках можно сделать обёртку.

Comment: Это преимущество не уникально. На C++ тоже можно делать библиотеки с С-интерфейсом и делать к ним обёртки для других языков.

Comment: Я имею в виду, что код C без изменения можно использовать в том виде, в котором он есть. А для других языков нужна обёртка.

Answer (score 6):

Потому что С простой как двери. Его легко выучить и использовать. И многие научные сотрудники и просто разработчики просто и разного софта без графических завоторов могут его легко освоить в отличии от от С++/Java где нужно учить что такое конструкторы, наследование, перегрузка операций и полиморфизм.

У него хорошая скорость исполнения и компиляции и занимает он промежуточное место между языками метапрограммирования (там где есть шаблоны и обобщения) и языками низкого уровня где есть почти-что прямой доступ к железу. Т.е. золотая середина между: может все и работает быстро.

Comment: Зачем в крестах или жабе учить что такое конструкторы, наследование и перегрузка операций? Если нужен простой язык — никто не мешает взять некое простое подмножество той же жабы и не трогать то, что не нужно. Зачем в жабе ООП, если достаточно одного статического класса-обертки и статических же методов в нем (и запомнить, что пишут не `length(foo)`, а `foo.length`).

Как гласит старая-старая шутка, на Фортране можно писать на любом языке.

В современном Паскале есть и перегрузка операторов и дженерики. Что не мешает школьникам не знать даже как декларируются функции, но уже успешно писать код.

Comment: Только что полностью осознал, какой же Си примитивный язык. Даже перегрузки нет. Ужас!

Comment: @Shamov, " Даже перегрузки нет. Ужас!".

А может это  наоборот - правильно? Сразу видно, что конкретно вызываем. 

Достаточно проблем с традиционными операциями: +,-,== и т.п.

Comment: В большинстве случаев конкретика не нужна. Наоборот, хочется обобщённости. И пусть перегрузка настоящей обобщённости не даёт. Всё равно приходится делать отдельную функцию для каждого типа аргумента. Но зато хотя бы в момент вызова можно представить себе, что это одна и та же функция.

Comment: @Shamov, это Вам в *своих программах* хочется. Причем в тех, которые сейчас пишите.

А вот при поиске логических ошибок в *чужом* коде...

Comment: Я не сторонник идеи о том, что будто бы можно вносить удачные изменения в чужой код, предварительно не разобравшись в нём настолько, чтобы он был так же понятен, как свой.

Comment: }}}Зачем в крестах или жабе учить что такое конструкторы, наследование и перегрузка операций? 

Потому что разработчик, который выучил его подмножество функционального программирования, рано или поздно наткнется на чужoй код в котором все множество операций С++ или Java используется. И ему придется в них разбираться. А он их не понимает. Для него это будет что-то вроде: А это че за фигня?. И ему придется тогда учить весь язык или биться головой об стену и звать программиста С++.

Так зачем ему использовать язык, который обладает большим функционалом чем ему нужно и тратить на это лишнее время

Comment: Научные сотрудники с Фортрана и то со скрипом на С переходят. Потому что знают Фортран и им он полность подходит для их задач. Решая их почти полностью.

А вообще о вкусах и предпочтениях не спорят. Ибо сколько людей - столько и мнений. И кричать: "Все на освоение С++ или Java" бессмыслено и бесполезно.

Comment: Си действительно относительно нетрудно выучить, а вот использовать... не всегда. Есть такой формат представления географических данных - NetCDF. Для работы с ним имеется набор библиотек для разных языков. Описание API для Си занимает около 300 стр, для C++ - около 50 и соответственно пропорциональна трудности использования. Набор функций для Си - что-то совершенно жуткое, а набор классов на С++ - одна красота и удовольствие.

Comment: Правда есть и обратный пример. В GTK+ связать с событием виджета какую-нибудь callback функцию - раз плюнуть, а в Qt - для привязывания слота иногда приходится целый новый класс писать.

Comment: С Фортрана на Си во многих случаях и нет смысла переходить: производительность программ достаточно близкая, а писать для математических расчетов на Фортране очень часто проще. Вот другое дело, когда старые фортранщики пишут программы на нем для достаточно тривиальных парсингов баз данных в простом текстовом формате (просто строки чисел в несколько столбцом) - это очень мрачное зрелище. Им говоришь: освойте за месяц основы Питона и будет вам счастье. Так они просто привыкли и не хотят.

Comment: @Shamov "что будто бы можно вносить удачные изменения в чужой код, предварительно не разобравшись в нём настолько, чтобы он был так же понятен, как свой."

Во-первых бывает по всякому. Иногда это необходимо. Во-вторых: изменим чуть задачу -- код свой, но по прошествии времени основательно позабытый.

Comment: Если свой, но позабытый, то надо сначала всё вспомнить, а уже потом пытаться вносить изменения. Я против того, чтобы программировать, не приходя в сознание. Если отсутствие в языке перегрузки - это единственное, что поможет внести изменения в код без ошибок, то в этом случае лучше вообще ничего не делать.

Comment: @Jack Black: Объяснять суть таких вещей сложно, показать на практике — тривиально, вот черный ящик, сделаешь вот такие магические пассы — и будет тебе кролик в шляпе.

Сами использовать в своем коде просто так не научатся, а вызвать чужой — не проблема. Для примера, многие тысячи рельсообязъянок понятия не имеют как оно устроено и работает, очень слабо знают Ruby, пугаются от одного вида `class << self`, но знают волшебные конструкции и прекрасно лепят сайты. А если им подсунут вдруг поковыряться в кишках серьезного проекта… Да кто ж им подсунет-то, с такой квалификацией? Так и с Java или C++

Comment: > В GTK+ связать с событием виджета какую-нибудь callback функцию - раз плюнуть, а в Qt - для привязывания слота иногда приходится целый новый класс писать.

В простых случаях, да. Зато забацать кастомный виджет и затем его многократно использовать в Qt очень легко, а в GTK+, если нужна, например, специальная форма коллбэка, нужно погружаться в дебри, писать свои маршаллеры, что и само по себе невесело, так еще и доки очень сухие и обрывочные.

И это очень показательно. Для простых вещей C++ кажется громоздким, но с ростом объема кода помогает уменьшать сложность (если руки прямые).

Comment: Мы уже скатываемся к вопросам вкусов и предпочтений, и о том кто, какие проекты и для чего пишет. Не все программы ограничиваются Web-программированием и GUI. Есть еще куда демонов, утилит, инсталляторов, консольных программ, ядер ОС и прочего, для чего проблемы как оно работает и скорость очень важны. Там нужны программисты другой квалификации, с другими знаниями и другими языками программирования. Я не вижу смысла дальше обсуждать этот вопрос, а то начнется священная война, аля джихат С против всех не правоверных языков программирования :-). Но мы ведь сюда не за этим пришли. Правда?

Comment: Дело в том, что C язык не только простой — C язык нищий. И каждый проект на C сложнее «Hello, world» — это свой собственный монастырь со своими правилами. Так легко ли для каждой программы учить новый язык? Причем, замечу, как правило — без документации. Есть `lists.h` с набором `struct`'ов, `#define`'ов и функций — и, давай, вникай.

Легко каждый раз разбираться как автор вот в этом своем проекте сделал обычные списки или хэшмапы, как облагородил их макросами, чтобы код был удобен, как в этом проекте сделал управление памятью (с учетом параллелизма) и т.д.? Нет, C простым не назвать.

Comment: Тем не менее на этом нищем языке написано ядро Linux, GNU LIBC и много чего еще, и продолжает писаться. Давайте закончим этот идеологический спор. Тем более что я вообще люблю не С а ассемблер. Но кричать что это самый лучший язык и он очень понятный, простой и вообще супер, я не намерен. Свои задачи - свои языки. На С писать для веб - это как микроскопом ввинчивать дюбеля (они без резьбы) в бетон. На Python писать драйвера, или ядро системы - это как если бы прикрутить циферблат от БигБена к наручным часам. Каждый язык для своих задач и не стоит об этом спорить. Спор окончен. Всем расходится

Comment: @Jack Black: Ваши бы слова, да разработчикам в уши. Когда они берут C и начинают писать на нем очередной проект. Потому что «так принято», потому что они считают C «простым языком.»

Когда я вижу на C DHT-таблицу, драйвер домашнего low-end принтера или очередной парсер конфигурации — в общем, вещь, где никакие плюсы C явно не нужны, а общий объем кода сравнивается с полезной частью не в лучшую сторону — мне становится неприятно. Особенно, если в этом приходится копаться руками, а не просто наблюдать. За это я не люблю C-монокультуру в *nix.

А в остальном Вы полностью правы. У всего свои ниши

Answer (score 4):

Потому что по нему соскучились

Comment: спасибо, подняли настроение :D

Comment: @d9k, если откровенно, Вы не любитель чистого Си?

Comment: Скоро по ассемблеру соскучатся, а там и до машинного кода недалеко. Вот веселуха пойдет!

Comment: @mikillskegg, шутки шутками, а скорость библиотеки @Jack Black (на ассемблере) впечатляет.

Comment: @avp, я совершенно не удивлен, поскольку сам чем-то подобным одно время занимался, хотя и не с таким размахом и глубиной. Но использовать его для всего подряд... возраст и семейное положение не позволяют. Если алгоритм распараллеливается, я лучше за время, на порядок меньшее, напишу программу на cuda и получу приращение скорости раз так в 20-30.


Да вобщем-то многие математические библиотеки, особенно коммерческие, в значительной части написаны на ассемблере примерно в том же ключе, что и библиотека @Jack Black.

Comment: @mikillskegg, это бесспорно. Я последний раз писал на ассемблере лет 25 назад. 

Сейчас уже наверняка не буду, но (это как в спорте) не могу не порадоваться за других, кому рекорды еще подвластны.

Comment: }}}Да вобщем-то многие математические библиотеки, особенно коммерческие, в значительной части написаны на ассемблере примерно в том же ключе, что и библиотека Jack Black.

Моя, конечно, не коммерческая, но и писалась не из чистого любопытства или спортивного азарта, а для решения вполне конкретных задач. Когда кода стало много, решил что пусть он живет своей жизнью и будет открыт всем желающим. Так и родился проект. За одно приятно если твои наработки будут полезны еще кому-то.

P.S. Кстати через пару дней у нее будет С-шный интерфейс. Еще один полюс в сторону С. Спасибо @avp за идею.

Answer (score 3):

Видеокодеки. Во всяком случае дюже популярный x264. 
Ядра ОС, хотя тут не уверен.

Answer (score 2):

Если взять во внимание язык Obj-c, то это язык для мобильных устройств, в частности Apple.
Obj-c очень похож на С, и все вопросы справедливые для С справедливы и для первого. Отсюда и возросший спрос на С. Ведь последние годы спрос на новое мобильное ПО только растет.

Comment: @arnoldx, Obj-c и Objective-C это одно и то же? 

Просто в приведенной в вопросе картинке для Objective-C есть график. И он очень хорошо растет в последние годы.

Comment: То что Obj-C является подмножеством C не делает второй популярнее.

Многие знакомые программисты под iOS не знают C в достаточной мере, думаю с незнакомыми разрабами ситуация та же.

ЗЫ. и Objective-C это не только мобильные устройства на базе iOS, но и Mac OS X.